# trying to do an update and im getting these errors. im running ubuntu 21.04

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
Ign:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease
Ign:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates InRelease                                               
Ign:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports InRelease                                             
Ign:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security InRelease             
Err:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/cappelikan/ppa/ubuntu hirsute InRelease
Err:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Err:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::16 80]
Err:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04 (Hirsute Hippo) End of Life reached on January 20 2022: https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2022-January/000276.html

Comment: what do i need to do?

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 21.04 (Hirsute Hippo) reached its end of life on January 20 2022.
This was announced in [a message to the Ubuntu announce mailing](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2022-January/000276.html) list in January of 2022.

The message says to upgrade to Ubuntu 21.10 (Impish Indri). Still, since *that* release reached its end of life on July 14 2022, you could consider upgrading to the Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish) release instead. This is what [the Ubuntu 21.10 end-of-life announcement suggests](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2022-July/000281.html).

It also makes more sense to follow an LTS release if you are not updating your installed packages more often than once every few months.

Instructions on upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS are available in [the Ubuntu community wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/JammyUpgrades) (which also contains links that will eventually take you to [the EOL upgrade article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades)).

Comment: ill be updating more often than every few months