# apt update; ignore 404 errors (repository not found)

Tags: apt

tl;dr `apt-get update` fails to contact a repository in the list which is treated as an error; how can I ignore that error?

When I run an apt update I see

```text
$ apt update
...
Err:5 https://packagecloud.io/ookla/speedtest-cli/debian bullseye Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 54.215.143.248 443]
...
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://packagecloud.io/ookla/speedtest-cli/debian bullseye Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

This causes `apt-get` to return process code non-zero, and the calling script then fails.

I know I could edit the repositories under `/etc/apt`. But in this case, I would like to have `apt` ignore errors like this, and have `apt-get` return process code zero (assuming nothing else goes wrong).

For moderators, this question is different than similar questions ([1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/720862/sudo-apt-update-allow-unauthenticated-gives-error-the-repository-has-no-relea), [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/715846/trying-to-do-an-update-and-im-getting-these-errors-im-running-ubuntu-21-04), [3](https://superuser.com/questions/1671110/debian-apt-get-update-404-not-found-error)) because I'm asking to temporarily ignore missing repositories. Whereas other Questions and Answers are asking for the permanent fix (requiring changes under `/etc/apt`).

Comment: Did you found a solution to this?

Comment: @gxx I have not 